# update the section header value after a search is performed

Tags: ios

I have a UITableView that implements UISearchBarDelegate. I have two sections in my self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView and would like to update the UILabel in these with the number of returned results. What is the best way to do this?

I am using CoreData.

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to handle the appropriate value-grabbing in your `UITableView` data source method `- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section`. Then, once you get the new values (and populate whatever source you're going to use in that method), simply call `[myTableView reloadData]`.

So, let's say you're storing your header titles in an array called `HeaderTitles`. (**This assumes you've got an NSMutableArray/NSArray that is already populated with your section header titles**)

```
// This is a method I made up, which is where you get the data returned...
- (void)gotNewTitle:(NSString *)title forSection:(NSUInteger)section {
    [[self HeaderTitles] replaceObjectAtIndex:section withObject:title];
    [[self myTableView] reloadData];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [[self HeaderTitles] objectAtIndex:section];
}
```

If you'd rather not use an NSArray, since you've got 2 sections for sure, you could use the following method (which assumes 2 properties, both `NSString`, `FirstSectionTitle` and `SecondSectionTitle`):

```
- (void)gotNewTitle:(NSString *)title forSection:(NSUInteger)section {
switch (section) {
    case 0:
        [self setFirstSectionTitle:title];
        break;
    case 1:
        [self setSecondSectionTitle:title];
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
[[self myTableView] reloadData];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    switch (section) {
        case 0:
            return [self FirstSectionTitle];
            break;
        case 1:
            return [self SecondSectionTitle];
            break;
        default:
            return @"";
            break;
    }
}
```